# Integrating tesseract with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, ocr

I am currently working on Android project where I have to use tesseract library. I have downloaded source from [here](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-android-tools/source/checkout) and now I am trying to build it using steps from README from the source.

When I run command in cmd ndk-build -j8, I am getting errors:

```
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : lept <= open_memstream.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : lept <= fopencookie.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : lept <= fmemopen.c
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: lept <= box.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: lept <= pix.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: lept <= pixa.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: lept <= utilities.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: lept <= readfile.cpp
In file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/box.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h:
No such file or directory
 #include <allheaders.h> 
                        ^ 
coIn file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/pixa.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h:
No such file or directory
 #include <allheaders.h>
                        ^ 
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/pixa.o] Error 1 
make.exe: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs.... 
mIn file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/pix.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h:
No such file or directory
 #include <allheaders.h>
                        ^ 
pciolmaptiiloatnio n tteermrimniantaetde.d
.
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/pix.o] Error 1 
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/box.o] Error 1 
In file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/utilities.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h:
No such file or directory
 #include <allheaders.h>
                        ^ 
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/utilities.o] Error 1
In file included from jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/readfile.cpp:17:0:
jni/com_googlecode_leptonica_android/common.h:22:24: fatal error: allheaders.h:
No such file or directory
 #include <allheaders.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/lept/readfile.o] Error 1
```

How can I fix this?

P.S. I am working in Android Studio

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Comment: Yes and no...I used tess2 lib instead of tesseract...